# Holomorphic function constant on a lattice.

Tags: complex-analysis

Good morning,

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function such that for all $(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, $ f(n+im) = 0$. Is it constant ? I can't think to a counter-example, but such a result seems a bit strong to me.

Thank you for your help,

S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily: use [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) and enumerate $S:=\{n+im,(n,m)\in\mathbb Z^2\}$ as a sequence $(a_k,k\geqslant 1)$ (hence $|a_k|\to \infty$).

Actually, using again this theorem, one can see that the vector space of holomorphic functions which vanish at $n+im$ for each $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ is infinite dimensional.